# Отправить фокус в input, созданный в обработчике blur

Tags: javascript, html, focus

Следующий код создаёт новый input когда последний имеющийся теряет фокус в заполненном состоянии. Проблема в том, что при нажатии <kbd>tab</kbd> фокус переходит не в свежесозданный input, а куда-то дальше (в том числе, вообще за пределы страницы). Как исправить?

https://jsfiddle.net/smLfdrhu/

```js
document.body.addEventListener('blur', e => {
  if (e.target.value && !e.target.nextElementSibling) {
    e.target.parentElement.append(document.createElement('input'))
  }
}, true)
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: .25em;
}
```

```html
<main><input></main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливайте фокус принудительно на свежесозданном элементе, с помощью метода `focus()`:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('blur', e => {
  if (e.target.value && !e.target.nextElementSibling) {
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    e.target.parentElement.append(input);
    input.focus();
  }
}, true)
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: .25em;
}
```

```html
<main><input></main>
```

Comment: А проверить? Ну не работает же...

Comment: @Qwertiy: что именно не работает?

Comment: Вопрос был как сделать, чтобы фокус переходил на созданный инпут. Я нажимаю кнопку tab и фокус переходит на кнопку "мод" под ответом, а не на инпут. По-твоему, это работает?

Comment: @Qwertiy: разве не нужно уточнять в вопросе, что обязательна поддержка клавиатуры? ;-)

Comment: Ой.. Я мышью даже и не порверял... Этот код был среди тех, которые я пробовал. Кстати, я уже обнаружил, что такой же код, но обёрнутый в таймаут, более-менее работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy: чую, что ваш способ тоже не без недостатков. Вопрос то интересный, только необходимо чётко определить желаемое поведение.

Comment: Мой - с недостатками, я о них написал в своём ответе - мерцает фокус на другом элементе, а значит, потенциально может скроллиться страница. Если придумаешь лучше, будет круто. И ещё многовато возни с упихиванием вызова focus в реакт...

Answer (score 0):

Надо явно вызывать метод `focus` (свойство `autofocus` не срабатывает) и поместить добавление в `setTimeout` (микротаска через Promise не срабатывает).

Впрочем, есть не очень приятный момент с тем, что фокус успевает мигнуть на другом элементе, а потом переходит куда надо.

https://jsfiddle.net/jdmzskr0/3/

```js
document.body.addEventListener('blur', e => {
  if (e.target.value && !e.target.nextElementSibling) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var inp = document.createElement('input')
      inp.autofocus = true
      e.target.parentElement.append(inp)
      inp.focus()
    })
  }
}, true)
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: .25em;
}
```

```html
<main><input></main>
```